# how to dump data into a temporary table(without actually creating the temporary table) from an external table in Hive Script during run time

Tags: hiveql

In SQL stored procedures, we have an option of creating a temporary table "#temp"  whose structure is as that of another table that it is referring to. Here we don't explicitly create and mention the structure of "#temp" table.
Do we have similar option is HQL Hive script to create a temp table during run time without actually creating the table structure. Thus I can dump data to temp table and use it. Below code shows an example of #temp table in SQL.

SELECT name, age, gender
INTO #MaleStudents
FROM student
WHERE gender = 'Male'

Answer (score 1):

Hive has the concept of `temporary tables`, which are local to a user's session. These tables behave just like any other table, and can be created using `CTAS` commands too. Hive automatically deletes all temporary tables at the end of the Hive session in which they are created.
Read more about them here.

[Hive Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-TemporaryT)

[DWGEEK](http://dwgeek.com/apache-hive-temporary-tables-examples.html/)

Comment: Thank you Rohit. Appreciate your efforts in sharing the documentation.

Comment: If it helped you, just mark this answer as correct, and upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple temporary table. On this table you can perform any operation.
Once you are done with work and log out of your session they will be deleted automatically.

Syntax for temporary table is :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TABLE_NAME_HERE (key string, value string)
```